# Generic type function with different return type

Tags: kotlin

I'm running into an issue of knowledge right now and I'd appreciate any help you could offer. Here is my issue, I've got multiple function as such:

```
    fun read(key: Key, defaultValue: String): String? {
        return prefs.getString(key.name, defaultValue)
    }

    fun read(key: Key, defaultValue: Boolean): Boolean? {
        return prefs.getBoolean(key.name, defaultValue)
    }

    fun read(key: Key, defaultValue: Int): Int {
        return prefs.getInt(key.name, defaultValue)
    }
```

instead of overloading the `read` function with different type I'd like to use something like this:

```
fun<T> read(key: Key, defaultValue: T): T? {
    return when(defaultValue){
        is String -> prefs.getString(key.name, defaultValue)
        is Boolean -> prefs.getBoolean(key.name, defaultValue)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```

However the IDE doesn't let me because there is an issue with return type which isn't a generic Type, I know it's possible to do something like this but don't know how.
Could you give me a hand finshing the `fun <T>` ?

Comment: make the return type `Any?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A function with generic return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982750/a-function-with-generic-return-type)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this for any reasons. Overloading is the clearest way to go around, better to have a compile time exception instead of a runtime one.

Comment: I could make it `Any?` but it's not really that cleaner

Comment: @Daniel that's a good reason indeed, I was thinking about clarity of the code and possibly refactoring in a more beautiful way, and didn't think about possible crash

Comment: The overloading is very clear and it integrates excellently with IDE suggestion feature, since you know for sure what are the possible options without going to the source code of the function.

Comment: I would never go for such approach, it makes the code more unreadable. This approach is applied in dynamic typed languages and I think should be avoided when you have the possibility to declare types at compile-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, ***overloads are far better and clean approach***, but If you are dead set doing it this way, then you can use unchecked casts

```
fun<T> read(key: Key, defaultValue: T): T? {
    return when(defaultValue){
        is String -> prefs.getString(key.name, defaultValue) as T
        is Boolean -> prefs.getBoolean(key.name, defaultValue) as T
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```

Comment: `prefs.get*(..)` returns a nullable so it should be `as T?` I think

Comment: I'll do as @Daniel suggested in commentary in my post and use overloads instead of this function